# How to generate n random numbers from negative binomial distribution?

Tags: r, random, distribution

I am trying to make a function in order to generate `n` random numbers from negative binomial distribution.
To generate it, I first made a function to generate `n` random variables from geometric distribution. My function for generating `n` random numbers from geometric distribution as follows:

```
rGE<-function(n,p){
  I<-rep(NA,n)
  for (j in 1:n){
  x<-rBer(1,p)
  i<-1 # number of trials
  while(x==0){
    x<-rBer(1,p)
    i<-i+1
  }
  I[j]<- i
  }
  return(I)
}
```

I tested this function (`rGE`), for example for `rGE(10,0.5)`, which is generating `10` random numbers from a geometric distribution with probability of success 0.5, a random result was:

```
[1] 2 4 2 1 1 3 4 2 3 3
```

In `rGE` function I used a function named `rBer` which is:

```
rBer<-function(n,p){
  sample(0:1,n,replace = TRUE,prob=c(1-p,p))
}
```

Now, I want to improve my above function (`rGE`) in order to make a function for generating `n` random numbers from a negative binomial function. I made the following function:

```
rNB<-function(n,r,p){
  I<-seq(n)
  for (j in 1:n){
    x<-0
    x<-rBer(1,p)
    i<-1 # number of trials
    while(x==0 & I[j]!=r){
      x<-rBer(1,p)
      i<-i+1
    }
    I[j]<- i
  }
  return(I)
}
```

I tested it for `rNB(3,2,0.1)`, which generates 3 random numbers from a negative binomial distribution with parametrs `r=2` and `p=0.1` for several times:

```
> rNB(3,2,0.1)
[1] 2 1 7
> rNB(3,2,0.1)
[1] 3 1 4
> rNB(3,2,0.1)
[1] 3 1 2
> rNB(3,2,0.1)
[1] 3 1 3
> rNB(3,2,0.1)
[1] 46  1 13
```

As you can see, I think my function (`rNB`) does not work correctly, because the results always generat `1` for the second random number.
Could anyone help me to correct my function (`rNB`) in order to generate `n` random numbers from a negative binomial distribution with parametrs `n`, `r`, and `p`. Where `r` is the number of successes and `p` is the probability of success?

[[Hint: Explanations regarding geometric distribution and negative binomial distribution:
Geometric distribution: In probability theory and statistics, the geometric distribution is either of two discrete probability distributions:

1. The probability distribution of the number X of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set { 1, 2, 3, ... }.
2. The probability distribution of the number Y = X − 1 of failures before the first success, supported on the set { 0, 1, 2, 3, ... }

Negative binomial distribution:A negative binomial experiment is a statistical experiment that has the following properties:
The experiment consists of x repeated trials.
Each trial can result in just two possible outcomes. We call one of these outcomes a success and the other, a failure.
The probability of success, denoted by P, is the same on every trial.
The trials are independent; that is, the outcome on one trial does not affect the outcome on other trials.
The experiment continues until r successes are observed, where r is specified in advance.
]]

Comment: Why not use `rnbinom`? And where is `rBer` defined? Is it just `rBer <- function(n, p) rbinom(n, 1, p)`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AllanCameron. I do not want to use r functions like rnbinom. I want to make my own functions. I added rBer function to my above explanations.

Comment: I think I understand vahid. I see you are using the function `sample` though. Is this the only random - generating function you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will be much faster if you use R's native vectorization. The way you can do this is to generate all your Bernoulli trials at once.

Note that for a negative binomial distribution, the expected value (i.e. the mean number of Bernoulli trials it will take to get `r` successes) is `r * p / (1 - p)` [(Reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)

If we want to draw `n` negative binomial samples, then the expected total number of Bernoulli trials will therefore be `n * r * p / (1 - p)`. So we want to draw at least that many Bernoulli samples. For simplicity, we can start by drawing twice that number: `2 * n * r * p / (1 - p)` . In the unlikely case that this is not enough, we can draw twice as many again repeatedly until we have enough; once the sum of the resultant vector of Bernoulli trials is greater than `r * n`, we know we have enough Bernoulli trials to simulate our `n` negative binomial trials.

We can now run a `cumsum` on the vector of Bernoulli trials to keep track of the number of positive trials. If you then perform integer division on this vector by `%/% r`, you will have all the Bernoulli trials labelled according to which negative binomial trial they belonged to. You then `table` this vector.

The first `r` numbers of the table (obtained by subsetting the table by `[1:n]` or equivalently by `[seq(n)]` is your negative binomial draw. We just remove the table's names by using `as.numeric`. We also subtract the number of successes (i.e. `r`), from each of our counts, since we are only counting the failures, not the successes.

```r
rNB <- function(n, r, p) {
  mult <- 2
  all_samples <- 0
  while(sum(all_samples) < n * r)
  {
    all_samples <- rBer(mult * n * r * p / (1 - p), p)
    mult <- mult * 2
  }
  as.numeric(table(cumsum(all_samples) %/% r))[seq(n)] - r
}
```

So we can do:

```r
rNB(3, 2, 0.1)
#> [1] 14 19 41

rNB(3, 2, 0.1)
#> [1] 23  6 56

rNB(3, 2, 0.1)
#> [1] 11 31 59

rNB(3, 2, 0.1)
#> [1]  7 21 14

mean(rNB(10000, 2, 0.1))
#> [1] 18.0002
```

We can test this against R's own `rnbinom`:

```
mean(rnbinom(10000, 2, 0.1))
#> [1] 18.0919

hist(rnbinom(10000, 2, 0.5), breaks = 0:20)
```

[image]

```
hist(rNB(10000, 2, 0.5), breaks = 0:20)
```

[image]

Note that the logic of your own version isn't quite right. In particular, the line `while(x == 0 & I[j] != r)` doesn't make any sense. `I` is a vector of `1:n`, so in your example, whenever `j` is 2, `I[j]` is equal to `r` and the loop stops. This is why your second number is always 1. I don't know what you were trying to do here.

If you want to do it one Bernoulli trial at a time, as you are doing in your own version, try this modified function. The variable names should hopefully make it easy to follow the logic:

```r
rNB <- function(n, r, p) {
  # Create an empty vector of length n for our results
  draws <- numeric(n)
  
  # Now for each of the n trials we will get a negative binomial sample:
  for (i in 1:n) {
    # Create success and failure counters for this draw
    failures  <- successes <- 0
    
    # Now run Bernoulli trials, counting successes and failures as we go
    # until we hit r successes
    while(successes < r)
    {
      if(rBer(1, p) == 1) 
        successes <- successes + 1
      else
        failures  <- failures + 1
    }

    # Once we have reached r successes, the current number of failures is our
    # negative binomial draw
    draws[i] <- failures
  }
  
  return(draws)
}
```

This gives identical results to the faster, albeit more opaque, vectorized version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @AllanCameron. You used R's native vectorization. I can not understand your code conceptually. Inside while loop, you have used rBer function and its first argument is "mult * n * r / p", why? What does "mult times n times r divided by p" mean? As I have written my rBer function (rBer(n,p)), its first argument is n, which means generating n random numbers (0 and 1) from a Bernoulli distribution. Does "mult*n*r/p" match with the first argument of my rBer function? How do you find "mult*n*r/p" based on your mathematical computations?

Comment: I also do not understand why, firstly, you have assigned 2 to mult, and why in each iteration of while loop, you have multiplied mult by 2? Understanding "as.numeric(table(cumsum(all_samples) %/% 2))[seq(n)] - r" mathematically is one of the other challenges that I have faced with. Why %% 2? What does seq(n) do exatly? Why do we have minus r at the end (I mean -r)? @AllanCameron

Comment: Thanks again for your help @AllanCameron, your code is more professional and faster than my code. However, could you please help me how to correct my own function (rNB) for generating n variable numbers from a negative binomial distribution? What are my mistakes in my code (my own rNB function)?

Comment: @vahid I have spent considerable time amending my answer to make it clearer, including a section about what was wrong with your code, and a rewrite of your logic. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanations @AllanCameron. You explained very well. Now I understand your code conceptually.